# Checking for null selection variable value in the command framework of Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, command, eclipse-rcp, contextmenu, rcp

How can I check whether the `selection` variable value is `null` when I open the editor?

I want to activate a context menu command when the certain editor is opened, it is not dirty and nothing was selected by the user. First two coditions are working fine:

```
<and>
    <with
        variable="activePartId">
        <equals
            value="com.eclipse.someeditor">
        </equals>
    </with>
    <with
        variable="activePart">
        <not>
            <test
                 property="com.eclipse.isEditorDirty">
            </test>
        </not>
    </with>
<and>
```

My current problem is that the straightforward solution would be to include another condition:

```
<with variable="selection">
    <count value="0" />
</with>
```

Unfortunately when the editor is first opened, the count is not 0. It probably is `null`. If the user selects something and then deselects, it becomes 0. Any ideas how to check whether the value of selection is `null` or similar?

**UPDATE**

I also tried creating a property tester that checks whether the value of the selection is null, but the code is **not executed**. I think that it happens, because it does not even go inside the selection if the user did not select/deselect anything.

```
<with variable="selection">
    <test
        property="com.eclipse.isSelectionNullOrEmpty">
    </test>
</with>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'instanceof' and 'and'. Like:

```
<and>
 <instanceof value="fully_qualified_class_name_of_your_selection_class"/>
 <equals value="0" />
</and>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not help. The problem is that there is no selection when you open the editor. My main issue is that when I have only 2 conditions specified as described above, the command gets populated to the context menu of the inner table selection. That is why I want to make sure that the command is active only when nothing inside the editor is selected. It does work using the `selection count = 0`, but only when user selects/deselects something at least once. When you open the editor there is no selection and the command is not active.

Comment: May be you should try to set your menu item to the disabled state somewhere in the code, when UI is created?

Comment: It has to be a generic solution and easy to maintain and understand. See my answer below.

Comment: Cool, glad you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked:

I made the `Editor` a `SelectionProvider` that is capable of delegating to another `SelectionProvider` to be able to switch between them (e.g. when I have an inner table that provides selection as well and take procedence.

Then I set the `getSelection()` to return an empty `StructuredSelection` when there is no delegate (opposite to returning `null`). Thanks to that there is always a `StructuredSelection` being returned, but sometimes it is empty.

```
public ISelection getSelection() {
    return delegate == null ? new StructuredSelection() : delegate.getSelection();
}
```

After that I could add the simple condition that I mentioned earlier:

```
<with variable="selection">
    <count value="0" />
</with>
```

Some people may find this useful.